# Running shell script command after executing an application

Tags: linux, shell

I have written a shell script to execute a series of commands. One of the commands in the shell script is to launch an application. However, I do not know how to continue running the shell script after I have launched the application.

For example:

```
...
cp somedir/somefile .
./application
rm -rf somefile
```

Once I launched the application with "./application" I am no longer able to continue running the "rm -rf somefile" command, but I really need to remove the file from the directory.

Anyone have any ideas how to compete running the "rm -rf" command after launching the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by others, you can background the application (man bash 'job control', e.g.).

Also, you can use the `wait` builtin to explicitely await the background jobs later:

```
 ./application &
 echo doing some more work

 wait # wait for background jobs to complete 
 echo application has finished
```

You should really read the man pages and bash help for more details, as always:

- http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sh
- http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Builtins

Answer (score 2):

Start the application in the background, this way the shell is not going to wait for it to terminate and will execute the consequent commands right after starting the application:

```
./application &
```

In the meantime, you can check the background jobs by using the `jobs` command and wait on them via `wait` and their ID. For example:

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 2098
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &
$ wait %1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the command in the background using '&' and maybe even nohup.

```
nohup ./application > log.out 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

put the started process to background:

```
./application &
```